# Organizing vb.net project/solution

Tags: vb.net

Ia am trying to organize few vb.net projects on disk at way like I use to in VB6 but without success.

Problem is that "new project" option from IDE open's new root directory for solution and whole tree of subdirectoryes for project files, compiled project etc...

Why I would like to this "at old way"?
Because all of those projects uses same dependable directories like "images", "setup" etc.
Also, some VB files have to be "shared" through projects.

Then I try to dump all those files from several projects in one directory what don't work because subfolders have a same name (eg. "my project").

Is it possible anyhow to get such functionality with "normal way" of using vb.net?

... that my (release) exe's would be in main project directory and that in those directory I have more than one project with all files.

Comment: While I would strongly discourage you from including the same file in multiple projects and would recommend that you make a new common library project to contain those files, it is possible to do that same kind of thing through Visual Source Safe.  If you are using VSS, you can drag a file in VSS from one project to another to create a "linked" shared file.  When you check in changes to that file from either project, source safe will automatically update the one in the other location.

Comment: You should put all of your common resource in one project and reference that project (dll) in all of your different solution.

Comment: Thanks for recommendations but all of that sounds inpractical because I have to got a same underlying directory structure to have same functionality for all files. There would be differences in Application.Path what makes use of shared library among two projects - highly suspicious. Can't belive that few .NET projects cant be set to one single directory.